# Magento 2: Override di.xml in custom theme

Tags: magento2.3, di, override-model

I have a module in `vendor/company/module`. I have created the following folder to override files. 
`/vendor/theme/theme-frontend-default/Company_Module`.

I am able to override files in view folder but I also want to override model and maybe `di.xml` if required. Creating `di.xml` in `/vendor/theme/theme-frontend-default/Company_Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` does not override. Is there a different way to override di.xml or models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

di.xml files and models are considered "backend" code. Themes only deal with frontend code: layout, template, css/less, javascript, images, etc.

You must create a module to accomplish those backend tasks. I usually just create a module called MageModule_ThemeHelper or something like that just so I know its sole purpose is to help my theme.